Is ZFC-FA+$\{x:x\in x\}$ consistent? (relative to ZFC)
Let ZFC-FA be ZFC without the Axiom of Foundation (Regularity). It is well-known that asserting the existence of the Russell's set, $\{x:x\notin x\}$, makes the theory trivial. The same is true of, e.g., asserting the existence of the universal set, $\{x:x=x\}$, when combined with restricted comprehension.
My question is the following: Is the theory ZFC-FA+$\exists y\forall x(x\in y \leftrightarrow x\in x)$ consistent (relative to ZFC)? In (more or less) other words, does the assertion of the existence of the set $\{x:x\in x\}$ over ZFC-FA preserve the non-triviality of the theory?

Sure. In fact, ZFC already proves that that is a set (namely, $\emptyset$).

@NoahSchweber oh, sure. got it, thanks.

To strengthen what @NoahSchweber is saying, not only is $ \mathbf { Z F C } - \mathrm { F A } + \exists { x : x \in x } $ consistent (relative to $ \mathbf { Z F C } $); in fact, the stronger theory $ \mathbf { Z F C } + \exists { x : x \in x } $ is consistent, because it's equivalent to $ \mathbf { Z F C } $.

For a less-trivial answer: given an $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ we can build (a la Fraenkel-Mostowski) a cumulative hierarchy $M'$ on a single Quine atom. This $M'$ satisfies $\mathsf{ZF-FA}$ + "There is exactly one set which is an element of itself."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom is a an axiom that yields many "cyclic"/"self-referential" sets.

@sdcvvc ${x:x\in x}$ is not a set in AFA though (since it does yield “many” such sets).

@spaceisdarkgreen I was wondering whether it is, is there some easy explanation as to why not? or would you give some reference at least? thanks

@TimotejŠujan You were wondering specifically about Aczel antifoundation axiom?

@spaceisdarkgreen yes, I have here  Aczel's book opened, but did not find anything about the set above (so far)

@TimotejŠujan For any well-founded set $a$, AFA gives a unique set $z$ such that $z={z,a}$, so this produces a proper class of sets with $z\in z$.

Just to collect the comments into an answer.
It is consistent with $\sf ZFC - FA$ that $\{x: x\in x\}$ is a set, and also consistent that it is not a set.

In $\sf ZFC$, $\{x: x\in x\}$ is provably the empty set.
There are models of $\sf ZFC+\lnot FA$ in which $\{x:x\in x\}$ is a nonempty set, e.g. a universe over a single Quine atom, in which it is a set with one element. There are also models of $\sf ZFC + \lnot FA$ where $\{x:x\in x\}$ is the empty set, e.g. a universe over a double Quine atom (i.e $a\ne b$ with $b=\{a\}$ and $a=\{b\}$).
The two antifoundation theories I'm familiar with both prove $\{x:x\in x\}$ is not a set. For $\sf ZFC+ BAFA$, there are already proper-class-many Quine atoms. For $\sf ZFC+AFA,$ there is only one Quine atom, but still proper-class-many self-containing sets, as, e.g., each well-founded set $a$ yields a unique set $z$ such that $z=\{z,a\}.$

